# When I generate Spring starter project with eclipse STS tools there is an error occurs in pom.xml first line. But I found no error in pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, spring-tool-suite

I have created a Spring starter project with eclipse STS tool after creating project there is an error in pom.xml first. But I found no error. I have tried Updating project with and with out forcefully but error still persists

Thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!-- error occurs here -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.web-app</groupId>
    <artifactId>FirstWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FirstWebApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Project runs but not working.
[This is the image of eclipse workspace]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9fGB.png

Comment: Same problem occurs when create project from spring initializr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , this is the latest [well known problem](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547340) of Eclipse when working with Spring Boot 2.1.5.

The workaround  is to add the following to `pom.xml` :

```
<properties>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thank you. Problem gone

Comment: @ankurpramanik  , glad to hear . So consider to accept my answers or give me a vote up 