# pom.xml showing error after being downloaded from https://start.spring.io/

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

trying to follow a tutorial on developing web application with spring, thymeleaf, hibernate and mysql database. I created the project using https://start.spring.io/ after downloading the zip, pom.xml shows error marking the heading tag

i have ran maven build and maven clean, both is successful but the error still is not going.

//I get the error on the first line with no hint at all

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.codejava</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProductManager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ProductManager</name>
    <description>Spring boot CRUD web app Example</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! you've provided some useful details, but your question is still missing key information; what error message are you seeing?  at what point do you see the error message?  etc.

Comment: Is maven and jdk installed properly in your system, Also set the JDK in the build path in eclipse. Also try to remove the .m2 -> repository and try to import all the dependency again.

Comment: may be related to [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448445/when-i-generate-spring-starter-project-with-eclipse-sts-tools-there-is-an-error/56449066#56449066)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to downgrade your boot version to 2.1.4.RELEASE

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

OR

update your maven version to the newest one. [Download maven](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)

Comment: "Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.22.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.22.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org pom.xml/ProductManager line 1

Comment: that was the error I got from trying to downgrade to version 2.1.4 release and I have done maven update selecting force update but yet stil having the above error

Comment: thank you so much, this solve part of the project but didnt solve all.... after downgrading it then it starts showing another error that has to do with jdk. but i have resolved the error

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse then it's eclipse issue,if you can just run the spring project and  check whether is it running fine?
If it's running then don't worry.
Sorry for lot's of assumption as the question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem in eclipse.The projects generated from start.spring.io didn't have any packaging info jar/war.

```
<groupId>net.codejava</groupId>
<artifactId>ProductManager</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Now it is not showing any after adding "packing". Later maven>update project